# Using boost::asio::async_read with stdin?

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio, iostream

short question: I have a realtime-simulation which is running as a backround process and is connected with pipes to the calling pogramm. I want to send commands to that process using stdin to get certain information from it via stdout. Now because it is a real-time process, it has to be a non blocking input. Is boost::asio::async_read in conjunction with iostream::cin a good idea for this task?  how would I use that function if it is feasible? Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor`

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp

Comment: Will this block if stdin is a regular file instead of a TTY or a pipe?

Comment: Anyone have a solution for windows for this?

Comment: @MHebes There is a corresponding namespace for windows stuff in asio. You might want to take a look at the include header `<asio/windows/stream_handle.hpp>`