# Bypassing blocking input stream with C++/Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm currently writing something of a quiz program. This program throws questions at the user until a specified time limit runs out. How it's set up now is the quizzing functionality runs in a boost thread and the timing aspect is handled by a timed_join() on that thread. The problem I'm encountering is when the user is answering a question using cin, the thread will go past the time limit that has been established. Is there a way to have it interrupt the cin call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to read from `cin` asynchronously as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831253/using-boostasioasync-read-with-stdin) - updated link to example code is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp).

Answer (score 2):

You can read the input character by character in a non-blocking read by using `getchar`, `getch` or `getche`. If you've been looping long enough to reach the timeout, then stop looping :).

Comment: +1 for simplicity. For small project, it is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use other input methods. The readline library might be able to help you. Or if you are on Linux, you can go down to pure file descriptors, make `STDIN_FILENO` non-blocking like a non-blocking socket and use the `select` system-call and then you can get both the timeout and know when input is ready.