# Boost asio read from stdin asynchronously

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I want to read from standard input (in terms of c++, std::cin) with boost asio function async_read(). The following code does not compile and gives me a very long error message due to instantiation error. Can someone answer, how do I read from stdin asynchronously using this function?

```
char buf[64];

boost::asio::async_read(std::cin, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
                          [](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t size){});
```

Edit: I know there is a similar question already asked here [Using boost::asio::async_read with stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831253/using-boostasioasync-read-with-stdin), however it is not clear to me in which way the marked answer relates to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `posix::stream_descriptor`

For example:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
io_context ioc;        
posix::stream_descriptor input_stream(ioc, STDIN_FILENO);
// assume that you already defined your read_handler ...
async_read(input_stream, buffer(buf), read_handler);
ioc.run();
```

Note that you shouldn't mix the above code with `std::cin`

For more information please see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html).

Comment: Okay, this suffices to me, but still out of curiosity, it there a both windows and posix compatible solution?

Comment: Hi. you can try to bind the Console input with `windows::object_handle`